# Docker: How do I add myself to the docker-users group on Windows?

Tags: docker

I am getting the following error,

> The current user is not in the 'docker-users' group. Add yourself to
> the 'docker-users' group and then log out and back in to Windows.

How do I resolve this error on Windows?

Comment: I have this problem too, but in Windows 7 Home Premium...

Comment: i used to get this error in visual studio 2022 I try clean and rebuild the solutions sometimes works

Answer (score 199):

Run this command from an administrator command window to add your user id to the docker-users group and log back into your user account for it to take effect.

```
net localgroup docker-users "your-user-id" /ADD
```

`your-user-id` is your local Windows user name. You can determine this by looking at the folder name under C:\Users\ .

Comment: In case it's useful for somebody, if your user is in a corporate domain, you can do:
net localgroup docker-users "DOMAIN\your-user-id" /ADD

Comment: Worked for me by using: net localgroup docker-users "<my-system-name>" /ADD

Comment: I wonder why Docker Desktop does not display any hints to this simple solution.

Comment: I had to reboot after using this, then it worked! thanks!

Comment: What do I do if I get access denied?

Comment: your local user must be an administrator, and additionally, you should execute the aforementioned command from a powershell that you have previously executed as an administrator.

Comment: `your-user-id` is your local Windows user name.  you can determine this by looking at the folder name under C:\Users\ . For example if you have:  `C:\Users\Joe Bloggs` and you know that this is the user logged in, then `your-user-id` is `Joe Bloggs` with the double quotes around it, so the full command would be: `net localgroup docker-users "Joe Bloggs" /ADD`. I found this to work in my case - the command reponse was: `The command completed successfully.` Further advice from above is then to restart your machine for this change to take effect.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly after a log-off, log-on. Anyone who's not able to use the Users and Groups GUI to add themselves (because it keeps searching and doesn't find your name) should try this method.

Comment: You can also do whoami to find out your complete username. Separately do "whoami /groups" to find out if your username does in fact belong to 'docker-users'

Comment: if you're an AD user you need to put "AzureAD\user-id"

Comment: Type "netplwiz" in a windows run dialog (win + r) to get your username

Answer (score 12):

It might occur that the user-group "docker-users" not exist on your machine. In that case enter the following commands in the Powershell

```
New-LocalGroup -Name 'docker-users' -Description 'docker Users Group'

Add-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Administrators' -Member ('docker-users') –Verbose

Add-LocalGroupMember -Group 'docker-users' -Member ('Username','Administrators') –Verbose
```

Comment: when I run the first command in the powershell, following error occurs
New-LocalGroup : The term 'New-LocalGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: this did not grad docker access for my user, I am still seeing `error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running:`

Answer (score 5):

Try restarting the system, that worked for me, as it pushed me to the group automatically.

Answer (score 3):

If you are installing Docker Desktop from Chocolatey, you might only need a restart, as you are put in that group automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just uninstalled and reinstalled the docker and it is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exact same issue, just uninstalled and then re-installed docker desktop it worked.