# What are the practical consequence of the joining the "docker-users" group?

Tags: windows, docker, security

I use Windows 10 Home with a separate Admin account, using a limited account for day to day work. I've installed Docker (community edition) using the admin account, but when I switch to the limited user, it wouldn't let me run it unless my limited account joins the "docker-users" group.

This question isn't to ask how to join that group ([see this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61530874/3568)) but instead to to ask why the group is needed. Is this a security measure? Do I open up a vulnerability by using Docker from a limited account?

If it isn't a security measure, what reasons would I have for denying a user membership of this group?

Answer (score 0):

Being able to create docker containers should be considered a privileged action because it allows someone to host new services on the underlying server, including hosting interfaces on low-numbered ports (22, 80, 443 etc).

The "docker-users" group exists to allow non-admin users to perform these privileged actions, bypassing the security control that required an admin user. This exists for the convenience of managing docker containers from a standard user rather than an admin user. The security benefit of this is that you can further lock down your admin account as you no longer need to constantly access it for docker management. The downside is that the compromise of any account in the "docker-users" group could result in a compromise of your whole docker environment.

In the case where you are the only one using your PC, then it doesn't have much impact because if someone were to compromise your account, you would have bigger issues anyway. In shared computer environments, you may have some select users with the privilege to use docker, but allowing all user would significantly increase your attack surface, and allowing no users would mean you have to provide each user that requires access to docker with a privileged account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've never had any trouble listening on low-numbered ports on Windows with a limited account. Also, is the docker environment shared between all users?